# MPAndroidChart Changing Color of Text Above Each Bar in Barchart

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart

does anyone know how to change the color of the text shown above each bar in MPAndroidChart Barchart? Currently, the text color is a shade of black/grey which makes it invisible given my current theme. I am new to MPAndroidChart [Screenshot of Barchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JULRN.jpg)

Comment: I just found out how, For anyone with the same issue, the solution is barData.setValueTextColor(Color.WHITE);

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.